# Linux shell script check command success

Tags: shell-script, test

I need to check the command executed is success or not, I have place the below code in test.sh run it, which give the out by listing the content of `/home` but there is a warning

```
./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: [[: not found
```

What's wrong in below command

```
#!/bin/sh
ls /home/
if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
echo "Commnad Error"
else
echo "Commnad Success"
fi
```

Comment: There is no need to check the status of the previous command. You can and should do something liike `ls /home 2>/dev/null || echo "Command Error"`.  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to error:

```
./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: [[: not found
```

Your `/bin/sh` isn't `bash` and `[[` is bash-specific. Use single bracket `[` or `test` command by itself.
And also use `-ne` for numeric conditionals. `!=` will work in your specific case, but it's bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

The error is at `if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then`

number comparison is not done using `!=` Instead `-ne` is supposed to be used.

[Read here for numeric comparison](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Numeric_comparison)

Also, the correct sytax for the status of the last executed command exit code is `$?` without the quotes.

`if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then`

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with syntax error also there was no need of `[` twice, I changed the code to ` if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then` and working.

Comment: that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `dash` to execute the script because the `/bin/sh` is a `link` so you can instead using `bash` like `#!/bin/bash` then that warning

Answer (score 0):

Dash doesn't have `[[`, only `[`.
But even with `[`, there are reasons to prefer `if your_command`  over `your_command; if [ $? = 0 ]`. (The former is more straightforward, faster, and resilient to failures in `set -e` mode).